# why ssh Local Dynamic forward doesn't work on centos

Tags: networking, ssh, centos7, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I wanna to create a local dynamic forwarding in centos without using another machine as a proxy.
so I used dynamic forward command and is working fine in one of my centos vms as vm1.

```
ssh -fN -D 0.0.0.0:8090 root@localhost
```

**but in another machine (vm2) doesn't work properly. looks like there is a network routing issue or something like that in localhost!** because if i using vm1 as proxy to vm2 forwarding traffic will be work fine.

```
ssh -fN -D vm1:8090 root@vm2
```

- both vms sshd config files are the same.

Comment: just guessing, check if second vm is not already listening on port 8090

Comment: lsof -i :8090
ssh     12997 root    4u  IPv4 7696789      0t0  TCP *:8090 (LISTEN)
just ssh...